# height is added to the <h> tag by itself

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

My **original code** is

```
<h4 class="orange2" ><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>v/<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3);?>/<?php echo $v['uniq'];?>"><?php echo trim(strip_tags($v['video_name']));?> </a></h4>
```

**CSS** for orange2 is

```
.orange2{font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight:600;font-size:13px;color:#ef9950;margin:10px;}
```

when i opened the code after inspect element on H4
then in **chrome** code is

```
<h4 class="orange2" style="height: 227px;"><a href="http://allvideolectures.com/v/o2355Um7qD/Martial-Arts-Weapons-Training-Kama-Techniques-in-Martial-Arts">Martial Arts Weapons Training : Kama Techniques in Martial Arts </a></h4>
```

and on **mozilla** is

```
<h4 class="orange2" style="height: 286px;"><a href="http://allvideolectures.com/v/o2355Um7qD/Martial-Arts-Weapons-Training-History-of-the-Kama-in-the-Martial-Arts">Martial Arts Weapons Training : History of the Kama in the Martial Arts </a>
```

i don't know from where this height is added from itself 
This is creating problem on Mozilla [Link is here](http://allvideolectures.com/courses/course/o2355Um7qD) When you try to **hover** on Any image

Comment: Why don't you add a `height` property to the class 'orange2'? That may solve your problem.

Comment: @Anthony that would not override inline styles unless he set it as !important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the page you've linked in your question, there is a JS code that is dynamically changing the height of the `h4.orange2` elements:

```
var maxHeight = 0;
$("h4.orange2").each(function(){
   if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); }
});
$("h4.orange2").height(maxHeight);
```

It seems that this is the root cause of your issues.

Comment: i cannot find it by view source!